# google drive apiの認証が上手くいかない。

Tags: python, python3, oauth, google-api, google-drive-sdk

[公式ドキュメント](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)を読みながらgoogle drive apiのアクセストークンを取得しようとしているのですが上手くいきません。

詳しい方、見て頂けないでしょうか？

ドキュメントにあるコードをスコープのみ変えて動作させています。
環境はmacのvagrant上にインストールさえれたubuntu14.04、Pythonバージョンは3.7

コードはエラーなく実行されURLが表示されブラウザでアクセスすると認証画面が表示されます。しかし、途中のリダイレクトのところでアクセス拒否となり止まってしまいます。

**考えられる問題**
vagrant側で受け付けているipが9000なのに対しリダイレクト先で返ってきたのを確認するとlocalhost:8080となるのでアクセスできないのではと考えています。

**個人的に考えたこと、やったこと。**
この8080を9000に変更することが可能でしょうか？
ダウンロードしたcredentials.jsonにhttp://localhostという項目があったのでここを変更すれば変更できると試したのですが、ダメでした。

**googleからリダイレクト？で返ってくるURL**
http://localhost:8080/?state=6lZYW90cMvHypAINsVJMoScxo7cThv&code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

**コード**

```
# Copyright 2018 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START drive_quickstart]
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

追記
認証はまだアプリに組み込まないのでテスト環境のつもりで、その他を選択しており認証リダイレクトの項目がないです。
token.pickleとは一体なんなのでしょうか？

[image: 認証画面]

追記2
pickleについて教えていただきありがとうございます。
ウェブアプリでリダイレクトURLを9000に変更しました。

[image: web認証画面google]

今度は最初のコンソール画面に表示されるURLで400エラーがでるようになってしまいます。localhost:8080とマッチしないと出てきます。

追記3
credentials.json

```
{"web":{"client_id":"xxxxxxxxx","project_id":"xxxxxxxxx","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_xxxcert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","redirect_uris":["http://localhost:9000"]}}
```

[image: 400エラー]

**追記4**
vagrant　ファイルに8080のIPを追加しドキュメント通り実行したのですが、8080のアクセス拒否が起こりました。本来コードを実行したあとにその後に表示される数値を入力してねと促す文章がプロンプトに表示され`input()`状態になるのですが、私の場合なにも文章は表示されずサーバが応答を待っているような状態になりす。`ctr + c`で終了させると`flow.run_local_server()`でプログラムがループをおこしているようでした。認証のコールバックページでエラーが起こります。
サーバlocalhost:8080を立ててmacにインストールしたブラウザからアクセスできたのでファイアウォールではないと考えます。

**追記5**

400エラーは認証画面のリダイレクト追加でhttp://localhost:9000/で上手くいきました。スラッシュが必要みたいです。

Comment: もしもclient ID, client secretが入った``credentials.json``ファイル内にある``redirect_uris``の値が``http://localhost:8080/``になっている場合、``credentials.json``ファイルをダウンロードしたページを開いて、該当するクライアントをクリックし、「承認済みのリダイレクト URI」で変更することができます。OPと同一環境ではないため、検証しない状況下でのコメントになり恐縮です。それでもダメな場合は、別の環境で``token.pickle``を作成してそのファイルをコピーして使用することも可能かと思われます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。その他の項目が見当たりません。追記をしましたのでお力をお貸しいただけないでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問を更新していただき有難うございます。追加された画像から、クライアントIDを作成する際に「その他」として作成していることが認められます。この場合、redirect_urisは、自動的に``urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob``と``http://localhost``に固定されます。そこで、redirect_urisを変更できるようにするため、クライアントID作成時に「ウェブ アプリケーション」として作成してみてください。これにより「承認済みのリダイレクト URI」の項目で変更できるようになります。また、追記されたご質問にある``token.pickle``は、OAuth2を認証してコードを取得し、リフレッシュトークン、アクセストークンを取得した場合に毎回コード取得を行わないで済むようにリフレッシュトークンを保存しているファイルです。これをどこかで作成した後、別のところで使用するのもありかと思い、別案として提案させていただきました。最近、pickleが使われるようになりました。

Comment: 上記のやり方では上手くいきませんでした。

Comment: うまくいかないとのことでご迷惑をお掛けし、大変申し訳ありません。次の項目をご確認ください。1. 設定するのは「承認済みのリダイレクト URI」だけで問題ありません。2. エラーメッセージの画像から「承認済みのリダイレクト URI」に対して``http://localhost:9000``が設定されているにもかかわらず、``redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080``としてアクセスしていることが認められます。そこで、「承認済みのリダイレクト URI」を変更した後は保存ボタンを押して変更した``credentials.json``を再度ダウンロードし、ファイル内の``redirect_uris``が``http://localhost:9000``に変更されているかどうか確認した後、再度スクリプトを実行してみてください。

Comment: そんな、こちらが勝手にエラーにハマって尋ねているだけなので謝らなくて大丈夫です。credentials.jsonの中身を追記したのですが、9000でも上手くいきませんでした。その他、にして行うと認証許可するところまで上手くいきます。この2つでは何が違うのでしょうか？

Comment: 即解決できる提案をすることができず貴重なお時間を奪う事態になっており本当に申し訳ありません。残念ながら「credentials.jsonの中身を追記した」の意味が理解できないことと、そちらの状況の再現ができません。こちらでは「ウェブ アプリケーション」、「その他」で問題なく動作しています。そこで、別の環境で``token.pickle``ファイルを作成し、それを利用することを提案させていただきます。それでも動作しない場合は、こちらで認識できていない他の問題の可能性を懸念します。これについては私自身の知識不足によるもので謝罪致します。

Comment: いえいえ謝らないでください。大丈夫です。「credentials.jsonの中身を追記した」というのはダウンロードしたものがこれです。というだけで特に意味はありません。そちらはvagrant での実行でしょうか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません。「credentials.jsonの中身を追記した」の意味は理解できました。通常はそれで問題ないと思います。また、仮想環境並びに通常環境で特に問題なく動作しており、そちらの問題を再現できません。別の環境で作成した``token.pickle``を使用した場合の結果はどのようになりましたでしょうか。

Comment: 返信が遅れてしまい申し訳ありません。token.pickleを使用した方法ですがtoken.pickleが作成されてないのでできません。手動で作成することが可能なのでしょうか？もう質問なのですがGCPのプロジェクトはapi事に作成が必要でしょうか？GAEでbotを運用しているのですがそのプロジェクト内でgoogle driveのapiを使用しようとしています。プロジェクトについてイマイチ認識ができていないようです。

Comment: ご返事有難うございます。``token.pickleを使用した方法ですがtoken.pickleが作成されてない``についての詳細をお教えいただけないでしょうか。また、ご質問には``環境はmacのvagrant上にインストールさえれたubuntu14.04、Pythonバージョンは3.7``とありこれについて再現できるかどうかチェックしていましたが、今回いただきましたコメントでは``GAEでbotを運用しているのですがそのプロジェクト内でgoogle driveのapiを使用しようとしています。``とあります。環境を変更したとの理解で宜しいでしょうか。理解できないため、お力になることができず申し訳ありません。

Comment: 上記の認証用コードをみるとwith open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)と書いてありこれは認証が上手く行ったあとに作成されると思います。まず現状認証が上手く行かずに困っており言い換えればtoken.pickleが作成されずに困っている状態です。

Comment: localの環境は変更しておりません。ひとつのプロジェクト内でgoogle drive apiを使用したいのになぜか勝手にQuickstartなるプロジェクトが作成されていたのでどういう仕組なのか気になったためたずねました。

Comment: 残念ながら、まだそちらの状況を再現するに至っておりません。もしも再現することができ、明確な解決策が見つかりましたらご報告させていただきます。これは私の知識と経験の不足によるものです。申し訳ありません。

Comment: いえいえこちらこそ申し訳ありません。うまく説明できずに

Comment: Tanaikeさん原因が分かりました。認証で9000の後に/を付けなければならなかったようです。それで400のエラーは取れたのですが、その先でエラーにつまずいてしまいます。お時間ある時に見て頂けないでしょうか？https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54524/127-0-0-19000%E3%81%A7listen%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%81%AB%E3%83%9B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E5%87%BA%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84